# WPF C# - get python version by cmd

Tags: c#, python, wpf, command-line, cmd

I've try to taken python version, so i've start a process with cmd and a command "python --version".

I've try this for first:

```
     using (System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
              {
               p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
               p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
               p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
               p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/k C:/Python36/python --version";
               p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
               var retorno = p.Start();
              }
```

and opened a cmd window and returned this:

[cmd return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjYzA.png)

instead of this, i need this result returned to my WPF application, so i try this:

```
public static string GetPythonVersion()
    {
      string command = "python --version";
      string output = null;
      using (System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
      {
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format(@"/c {0}\{1} ", "C:/Python36/", command);
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        if (p.Start())
          output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
      }
     return output;
   }
```

return empty string to me.
however to an example if i using the same code to return "pip list" to my wpf application working well, but in this case to taken the version the string return empty....

Comment: you need to wait for it to end before you read the output.. otherwise it may not have printed it yet

Comment: i know, there is a function p.WaitForExit(int miliseconds); but in this case doesn't resolve the problem

Comment: Well, I tried it, new WPF application, one TextBox in the MainWindow, the exact same method to set the textbox's Text property (I even installed Python 3.6.5 at the same location), and it works. Your problem is somewhere else, but it's gonna be hard to tell where.

Comment: For Windows `cmd.exe`, the path separator is `\ `but not `/`...

Comment: i've tried again with the same Python version as you.. 3.6.5 and return the same string empty. I've read at Python official site about the "python --version" command  at [link](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#generic-options) and  said this : "Print the Python version number and exit"  so, there is a possibility when i send the command execute and put output to the python prompt then exit to pyton prompt.. and then my output about version doensn't exist more at the normal windows command prompt ?

Comment: So @aschipfl try to execute the first option of code.. this is not the problem :( , but thanks to all for trying help me

Comment: Maybe you need to specify `\\ ` due to escaping by Python?

Comment: why run cmd.exe why not just run python itself?

Comment: because if the user has more then one installation of python and i need to run in a specific installation.. then.. if i only call "python" instead "cmd".. the command will run in the python installation at root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, guys.I've discovered what is wrong on the code. Below the correct code:

```
public static string GetPythonVersion()
    {
      string command = "python --version";
      string output = null;
      using (System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
      {
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format(@"/c {0}\{1} ", "C:/Python36/", command);
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        if (p.Start())
          output = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
      }
     return output;
   }
```

yeah, the python version is on StandardError, because, as you can see on :

https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#generic-options

"*Print the Python version number and exit.*"

So when run the command on cmd, at the StandardOutput there is nothin...
thanks to everyone for trying to help me ! now this case is over!